# Variable1 value exists in variable2 script

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with sample1 and sample2 Columns. Some of the sample2 values exist in sample 1.
Now I want to extract a table where sample2 value is NOT available in sample1. Please see the tables below for clarification.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your sample data is inconsistent with your description. E & I are in your sample 1 and sample 2 but still show on the output table

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.sample1 = t.sample2);
```

Comment: @mumid . . . `NOT EXISTS` is better with a subquery because it handles `NULL` values intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

You basically said the answer in you question. Make sure `Sample2` is `NOT IN` `Sample1`

---

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Sample2 NOT IN (SELECT Sample1 From Table)
```

Comment: You are welcome. You have been faster than me and here is a oracle fiddle if you want to attach it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e71ad151dee15c5bd330a054628136e4 cheers

Comment: Trying to practice. Answering questions is how I learned my first language so moving onto SQL. I don't know how to use fiddle but will look at what you shared! Super useful